# JavaScript get page coordinates of closest clicked character

Tags: javascript, position, selection

I have a div tag with a bunch of text in it.

```
<div>Lots of text in here</div>
```

I am listening for onclick events from the div. I would like to insert a fake text cursor wherever the user clicked in the div. I can easily get what character was clicked with:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.focusOffset;
```

But I don't know how to get the pixel coordinates of that character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rangy library has a feature that does exactly this - find pixel position of selection. Take a look at this demo: http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/position.html

Library home: http://code.google.com/p/rangy/

Once you get the pixel position using rangy, you can dynamically add an absolutely positioned DIV (or reposition an existing DIV) to those coordinates.

Comment: So, does rangy add a dummy element at the beginning/end of the selection range, and get the coordinates from the element? Or does it do it another way? I really only need to use selection/ranges for this one thing, so it would be a shame to have to include the entire library.

Comment: I dont think rangy does that. It will give you the coords, what you do with the coords is upto you. But once you have the coords, adding/showing a dummy element (for cursor) should be straight forward. If you dont want to include the whole lib, you might want to check out its source to see how it determines the coords. One thing to consider is that rangy seems to be rather well tested across a lot of browsers, and might be better than custom code from a stability point of view.