# Place a div in the middle of a word with onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use JavaScript to place a div in the middle of another div while clicking on that div, however I'm having issues.

Example code:

```
<div>This is example text</div>
```

And I click the word example on the m, I want it to look like this,

```
<div>This is exam<span id='cursor'></span>ple text</div>
```

Now when I click the div again, I want the span to move to the new location:

```
<div>This i<span id='cursor'></span>s example text</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you should use the code you have so far? Are you using the Selection API?

Comment: I just updated my post to help answer that question

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611742/javascript-get-page-coordinates-of-closest-clicked-character

Answer (score 0):

Just done some testing on code pen and i hope this is what you're looking for

```
<div id="lol">This is exa<span id="cut" onclick="split()">m</span>ple text</div>
<script>
function split()
{
document.getElementById("lol").innerHTML = "This is exam ple text";
}
</script>

When the "m" which is spanned is clicked it doesn't move the span, but it replaces the text  which still plays the same role you explained that you want. If you want it to repeat this, just put the span with the onclick action in a different place, or have multiple
```